# How to call functions in the main function by use class?

Tags: class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Money
{
public:
Money();
Money(int, int);
void setDollars(int d);
void setCents(int c);
int getDollars() const;
int getCents() const;
double getAmount(int, int);

private: 
int dollars;
int cents;
};

Money::Money()
{
dollars = 0;
cents = 0;

}

Money::Money(int d, int c)
{
dollars = d;
cents = c;
}

void Money::setDollars(int d)
{
dollars = d;
}
void Money::setCents(int c)
{
if (c > 100)
{
    c = c % 100;
    dollars = dollars + (c / 100);
}
//update the dollars member if the cents input argument is 100 or larger. 
cents = c;
}

int Money::getDollars() const
{
return dollars;
}

int Money::getCents() const
{
return cents;
}


double Money::getAmount(int d, int c)
{
return dollars + (cents / 100);
}

int main()
{
int dlr;
int cts;
//double amt;

cout << "Please input amount of dollars: ";
cin >> dlr;
cout << "Please input amount of cents: ";
cin >> cts;

Money money0(dlr, cts);

cout << "The money object1 has amount: " << money0.getDollars() << "." << money0.getCents() << endl;
cout << "The money object2 has amount: " << money0.getAmount() << endl;
//I try to call the functions to tell user how much is it
//use both ways to tell user how much is it(1.getDollars+getCents, 2. getAmount)
return 0;
system("pause");
}
```

When I try to call the get functions in the main, the errors show up. How to call those functions correctly? 
Here is my assignment: 
Define a class named Money that stores a monetary amount. The class should have two private integer variables, one to store the number of dollars and another to store the number of cents.  Include a default constructor that initializes the amount to $0.00 and an overloaded parameterized constructor to initialize any non-zero amount(as demonstrated in the example program below).